# Why Intellij Idea doesn't show the current file?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

My current file is ServletConfig, but it can't show on the top of the tabs when there are many tabs.

Comment: Which version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the IDE adds new tabs to the right of active tabs. If the space exceeds the screen width, new tabs collapses behind the "show all"-button. This is the behavior you're expecting. New Tabs just collapses behind the "show all".

You have two options, disable the collapse-mechanism (eventually resulting in tiny tab headers that are not useful as well) or close least used tabs automatically. There is no "always show last opened Tab".

Check the [Editor-Tab Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/editor-tabs.html#close) to check if a setting fits your need.